# Trouble to generate header file for JNI

Tags: java-native-interface

I compiled `HelloWorld.c` successfully. I changed to the directory where `HelloWorld.class` is.
And I typed `javah -jni HelloWorld` in Terminal to get header file. I have the following error message. What is the problem? I am developing Android app using Mac OSX.

```
error: cannot access HelloWorld
bad class file: ./HelloWorld.class
class file contains wrong class: Test.HelloWorld
Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.

com.sun.tools.javac.util.Abort
javadoc: error - fatal error
2 errors
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that your HelloWorld.class is located in a subfolder Test. You are not expected to be INSIDE that folder but in the ROOT folder for your compiled package(s). So go out of that Test folder and try again `javah -jni Test.HelloWorld`

BTW i don't understand how you could "*compile your HelloWorld.c succesfuly*" if you don't even have the header yet. But i am answering what have been asked.

Comment: Oops! I compiled HelloWorld.java successfully. I am still figuring out    problem.

Comment: export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:~/MyProject/bin/classes must be done before doing javah -jni Test.HelloWorld.